# How to put onpress in each flatlist item

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm stuck in a problem, I'm making an app in react native, I created a horizontal flatlist as if it were a netflix menu and I managed to organize the components, but how do I put a link in each item to the next page, I tried with touchable but I can not.

```
<FlatList
  data={data}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => {}}>
      {/* Conteúdo do item */}
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )}
/>
```

I found this solution but I can't apply it

Answer (score 0):

You actually need to pass to `onPress` a function that does something:

```xml
<FlatList
  data={data}
  renderItem={({ item }) => (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => alert("Test")}>
      {/* Conteúdo do item */}
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )}
/>
```